# Disambiguation of sizeof

Tags: c

When using the `sizeof` I always enclose it in parentheses, as it's a bit easier for me to read, even if I can sometimes omit it, in the first case below

```
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-name )
```

My question is how does the parentheses disambiguate things to the compiler? What would be an example where something like:

```
sizeof char
```

Would be ambiguous to a compiler?

Comment: It is invalid, since `char` is not a unary expression. [BTW: I allways **omit** the parentheses if they are not needed, such as `struct stuff *p = malloc(sizeof *p);` ]

Comment: @wildplasser That's obvious enough, but the question is *why was this syntax chosen*.

Comment: Perhaps it is because a type can be more than one word but a variable identifier cannot.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica : because it mimics the cast syntax?

Comment: @wildplasser Excellent. Now type it up as an answer and you got it :)

Comment: Because back in the wild west days, there could be a macro inolved. `sizeof(X)` would invoke the macro rather than the built-in operator.  And I can't find my original version of the K&R book, but I seem to recall their examples may have done it that way.

Comment: It was only a guess. You should ask Brian Kernighan.

Comment: @WeatherVane *because a type can be more than one word but a variable identifier cannot* If this were a problem, it'd have been a problem elsewhere as well. As far as I can tell, the "single vs multiple words" problem causes no ambiguity as long as you have one token's worth of lookahead (as usually needed for C parsing anyway). The ambiguity appears, as wildplasser mentioned, as follows: `sizeof (void*)foo` vs `sizeof (void*)` - full backtracking is needed to resolve the ambiguity here.

Comment: You mean: the grammer woulldn't be LR1, anymore?

Comment: @jwdonahue IMHO macros are irrelevant here. The sizeof is performed after macro substitution has taken place.

Comment: @wildplasser, so it just might come down to whatever K&R wrote in their original text? I think all three of my editions are in a box in a steel shipping container at the moment.

Comment: @jwdonahue All *three* of your editions? There have only been two.

Comment: @KeithThompson, well they have been in that box for a very long time. Not sure why I thought there were three of them though. I hate getting old ;(.

Comment: Just a guess, but the current syntax `sizeof (type)` looks very much like casting an (invisible) expression to `type`, then taking its size.  Whether or not that's the reason, I find it a useful mnemonic.

Comment: For some extra sizeof fun: [sizeof(0)\["abcdefghij"\]](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/1269144668765188096)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If `sizeof` *type-name* were allowed, then `sizeof char * + 3` could be either:

- `(sizeof (char *)) + 3`, which is the size of a `char *` added to `3` or
- `(sizeof (char)) * (+ 3)`, which is the size of a `char` multiplied by `+ 3`.

Both of those would be valid parsings and fully defined by the standard (aside from the implementation-defined size of the pointer). So accepting `sizeof` *type-name* creates an ambiguity not resolved by the grammar or semantics.

### Earlier Example

If `sizeof` *type-name* were allowed, then `sizeof char [x]` could be either `(sizeof (char)) [x]` (which is a valid expression if `x` is a pointer or array; the subscript operator accepts `index[array]`) or `sizeof (char [x])` (which is a valid expression if `x` is an integer; it is the size of an array of `x` elements of `char`). Further, the grammar would provide no way to distinguish these; both would be valid parsings. Semantic rules could distinguish them based on the type of `x`, but then you have to parse before you can evaluate the semantic rules and would need some way for the compiler to undo the parsing.

Comment: Yep, the unary operators at the 2nd precedence level were the fly in the ointment I wasn't seeing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Accepting a typename after `sizeof` would not allow all types to be specified in an expression: pointer types (eg: `sizeof char * 10`) would create an ambiguity complicating the parse, which currently is quite simple.

Comment: `char * 10` is not a valid type in C. `(char*)10` is a valid *cast-expression*, and thus also a *unary-expression*.

Comment: `char * 10` is not valid C. I don't understand why one would bring it up. `(char*)10` is valid, `char* 10` is not, and this has nothing to do with sizeof.

Comment: There's still the `sizeof const char*` vs `sizeof( (const char*) )` conundrum, yes?

Comment: How about `sizeof char * + 10`? :-)

Comment: OK. I still don't get it. How about it? `char` is not a valid unary expression, with one level lookup. Doesn't take a GLR parser to deal with that.

Comment: @Kuba: Would that parse as `sizeof` applied to the type `char`, multiplied by `+10`? Or as `sizeof` applied to the type `char *`, with 10 added to it?

Comment: In terms of grammar I see now it's ambiguous, in terms of practical parsers I bet most are greedy and would gladly be building the *type-name* as long as they can. SDCC seems to behave that way, I'll have to check for similarly simple tweaks to gcc and other open source parsers and see how they'd behave if all that got changed was "let's drop the parentheses". I bet the original C's parser as-implemented would have been greedy on the type name as well. Of course a parser generator would catch the ambiguity, hand-written ones often quietly resolve those. All in all, it's an arbitrary choice.